# Security warning to save cookie when using Indy TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, cookies

I am developing a Delphi XE4 application that crawls a web site for certain information. It reads web pages with TIdHTTP and then parses with MSHTML using the IHtmlDocument2 interface.

The code works, but on one web site (www.orlytaitzesq.com), I get a Microsoft security dialog popup:

"Windows Security Warning
To allow this website to provide information personalized for you, will you allow it to put a small file (called a cookie) on your computer?"

It doesn't matter how I set "Allow Cookies" on the TIdHTTP component or whether I include a cookie handler. This warning just pops up randomly (following an Application.ProcessMessages) and my program stops until I respond to the dialog. This happens over and over again at random intervals. I have the Windows 7 Internet Options set to allow all cookies from the Internet Zone. I have IE 11. The web site I'm having the problem with is crawling with advertising.

I really don't understand what's happening, nor how to stop it.

Comment: Are you quite sure you aren't using the web browser control?

Comment: When / at which source location in your code exactly does this popup get triggered? Can you post the relevant code?